# I faced problem while compiling kernel module

Tags: kernel-module

Error: `*** No rule to make target 'Home' Stop`

There how I wrote my Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
                make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
                make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: I see nothing in the provided Makefile, which could cause the error about the `Home` target. What command do you enter to the command line for compile the module?

Comment: command 'make' in terminal

Comment: Please, add to the question post more portion of output. That is, some lines which precede the error message and the lines following it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to run and compile **Makefile** via command 'make' on linux version 5.11.0-38 faced problem when file didn't executed. There is screenshot of problem - https://i.imgur.com/OjknU5k.png or `make
make -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-38-generic/build M=/home/ash/MyProjects/OS Home Assignment/HA3/Code/Test modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Home'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your folder naming, instead naming the folder `OS Home Assignment`, name it with underlines `os_home_assigmnet`.
more details can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240219/make-command-does-not-work-in-directories-containing-space)